# How to change Chrome's data-directory when the previous user was locked?

Tags: google-chrome

The last user of this PC was sent away, his user is now locked, and in my user (I can execute as admin) when I try to open Chrome it shows this message:

[image]

- I tried this command:

> mklink /d "C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data" "C:\Users\washington.guedes\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data"

Without success:

[image]

- I also tried reinstall chrome and the message persists. =X

---

How can I change *user.name* to *washington.guedes*, stopping this message?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you only have one user profile on this system or something?  Why don't you just restart the machine?

Comment: @Ramhound I am the only to use the machine, but it has more users, and I can't do nothing with them.

Comment: I suggest you restart the machine.  That way the user who is logged into the computer will no longer be.  Once you do that talk to your IT department and have them properly configure Chrome on the system.  Chrome is suppose to place its user profile within the user's profile directory sounds like that's not happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to launch Chrome with a command-line-switch like

```
--user-data-dir "C:\Users\whatever..."
```

to force it to change user data folder?

You can find more command-line-switches at http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches

Hope it helps